# Gradle: How to exclude concrete package from project() dependency?

Tags: gradle

There is dependency's section from my gradle configuration:

```
dependencies {
    //..
    compile project(":first-project")
    //..
}
```

How can I exclude some packages from `:first-project` ?
Thx.

Comment: Do you want to exclude specific java packages? or transitive dependencies?

Comment: Yes. Java packages.